# cordova saving id in database

Tags: cordova

I have a project developed in cordova. Here I will create new tasks and list them in index.html. But in database, the "id" field is not storing the id (1,2,3...) dynamically. I want to know how to store the id dynamically in the project. Kindly help me in this. The js where I will create a new record is:

```
function addTask(task, cb) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO task (taskname) VALUES (?)",
                [ task.taskname ]);
    }, sqlErrH, cb);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out on how to do this.. The code is in create table.. :

tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, taskname)");

Here in id field, if we mention autoincrement, it will automatically increment the id.

Thanks